# How to select data from Google BigQuery table using api?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

Please, help guys.
I have this code:

```
            var request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert({
                projectId: projectNumber,
                resource: {
                    configuration: {
                        "query": {
                            "query": "SELECT mails FROM [test.test] LIMIT 10"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            request.execute(function(response) {
                $('#result_box').html(JSON.stringify(response.result, null));
                console.log(response.result);
            });
```

It returns 200, but I need to get all fields that I selected and work with each in js. How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Alex

Comment: I found where is the problem... It needs to be `gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query` instead `gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert`. Then I can get my data by `response.result.row`

Comment: Completely missed that. Welcome to stack overflow by the way ☺.

Comment: @AlexBondarenko: maybe you could post & accept that as the answer then, so that if others come across the same problem they'll easily be able to fix it :-)